# Java StringBuffer cannot print out apostrophe

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, symbols, stringbuffer

I would write a snippet that concats two string(with specific elements) to one. May someone could help me?

My code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           String first = sc.nextLine();

           String second = sc.nextLine();

          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(" ");
           for(int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++){
               builder.append(first.charAt(i));
               builder.append(second.charAt(i));
           }
           String base = builder.toString();
           System.out.println(base);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It seems English is not your mother language, I have trouble understand what you want... you may try a translator, might yield better results. Do you want to read two strings (s1, s2) from user input, then combine them together by combining them so it's s1[0] s2[0] s1[1] s2[1]... and so on? If so then your for loop is only operating on the length of s1, when s2 is longer than s1, trailing characters would be lost, and if s1 is longer than s2, then you will get an exception.

Comment: Keep answer as simple as possible. Remove all part which isn't need for the reproduction of error. (It is possible that during doing this you can correct your code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom,

The problem is that one string is longer than the other one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String elso = sc.nextLine();

   String masodik = sc.nextLine();

  String longestString = elso; 
  String shortestString = masodik; 
  if (shortestString.length() > longestString.length()){
    shortestString = elso;
    longestString = masodik; 
  }
  StringBuilder builderem = new StringBuilder(" ");
   for(int i = 0; i < shortestString.length(); i++){
       builderem.append(shortestString.charAt(i));
       builderem.append(longestString.charAt(i));
   }
   for(int i = shortestString.length(); i < longestString.length(); i++){
       builderem.append(longestString.charAt(i));
   }
   String alapba = builderem.toString();
   System.out.println(alapba);
}
}
```

Please let me know if it is working!